# How can I discard all of my Apache config files and start from fresh templates?

Tags: apache, config, lamp

I'm running the LAMPP stack on Ubuntu and I want to reset my Apache config files to a fresh default template. How can I do this?

Also, when editing the file `/etc/apache2/site-available/000-default`, should I also modify `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default` and `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalling Apache would be the easiest thing to do if it's a real mess:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2
```

But if you just need specific files then you can extract them from the Apache .deb file for your Ubuntu version.

Regarding the editing of multiple files, no - the files in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` are symlinks created when you enable a site using `a2ensite`. For example, you have the Virtual Host www.example.com defined in the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/www.example.com`:

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
$ sudo a2ensite www.example.com
$ cd ../sites-enabled
$ ls -la
www.example.com -> ../sites-available/www.example.com
```

Then reload Apache to make  the VHost www.example.com visible:

```
$ sudo service apache2 reload
```

To make changes to www.example.com just edit the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/www.example.com`. Then:

```
$ sudo service apache2 reload
```

To make the changes live. Anything that Apache finds in the sites-enabled directory is loaded into it's configuration on start up.